# How to use customize 404.html from decorator.py in django?

Tags: django, decorator

I have 4 types of user; client, officer, production_manager, service_manager. Therefore, I was creating 4 groups for each user. These users are my 4 apps in my project. In the corresponding `views.py`, in the methods, I'm using a decorator to give access only to a certain user, like this `@group_required('client_group')`. Here is my decorator method:

`check_group.py`

```
def group_required(*group_names):
    """Requires user membership in at least one of the groups passed in."""
    def in_groups(u):
        if u.is_authenticated():
            if bool(u.groups.filter(name__in=group_names)) | u.is_superuser:
                return True
        raise Http404
    return user_passes_test(in_groups)
```

Now if a client is logged in and trying to access a certain view from url , like, `officer/password`, then he cannot get access of that view. I am using `raise HTTP404`.

This is the structure of my project:

```
project
|-app
|-app
|-app
|-app
|-user_group
|--|--check_group.py
|--|--404.html
```

But the 404 page shown by django is its default. It's not taking my `404.html`.

Then in the `check_group.py`, I changed the code form my `raise Http404` to

`template = loader.get_template("404.html")
return HttpResponse(template.render())`

But then I'm getting an error

> officer/password doesn't contain any template 404.html

Then I put `404.html` in the `officer/template` but still getting the same error.

I want to use my customize `404.html` rather than django's built-in 404 from the decorator method, I mean, the method I wrote, `check_group.py`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by specifying handler in urls.py

```
handler404 = 'user_group.views.handler404'
```

Then you define view to render custom 404 html

```
def handler404(request):
    return render(request, '404.html')
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) is the documentation on customizing error views.

Comment: Can I write it in the `check_group.py` which is my `decorator class` ?

Comment: I believe that handler404 must be in the urls, but function that renders custom 404 html can be pretty much anywhere.

Comment: And what about the `raise Http404`? Should I change it too?

Comment: Leave it. The other option would be to replace raise Http404 with return render(request, '404.html'), but then that would render status code 200 and you probably want 404 status code returned.

Comment: Well if I keep `raise Http404` mentioned above, nothing happened. What I did is, in my `mainProjectFolder/urls.py` I added `handler404 = 'user_group.views.handler404'` after `urlpatterns=[...]` and in the `check_group` I created a `views.py` and added `def handler404(request):
    return render(request, '404.html')`. But like in the past django built-in `page not found` is rendering!

Comment: Include function handler404() in `check_group.py` and adjust variable handler404 in `urls.py` to point to 'user_group.check_group.handler404'.

Comment: still not working. Getting the default one. Do I have to turn off the `Debug`? `Debug = False`?

Comment: Yes, set Debug to False to see it.

Comment: Now I am getting `server error 500` and I have set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` and I also tried with `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Check logs and you'll see what the problem is. Did you import render from django.shortcuts? Is the path to 404.html correct?

Comment: yep I imported render from django.shortcuts and the path is also correct

Comment: @Borut the 404 handler should do `return render(request, '404.html', status=404)` - without `status` it will default to `200`.

Comment: He mentioned earlier in the comment to put it in user_group.check_group.handler404 So I put it int user_group.check_group. This is not the problem I guess

Comment: Well, check your logs already. Django looks for html templates in the dirs setup in `settings.py` and default path is /templates/. If you have your 404.html in user_groups folder, Django will return TemplateDoesNotExist exception.

Comment: Well, my `404.html` is inside user_group/templates

Comment: Check logs and you will see what the issue is. You can't debug by guessing.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this, but how to check logs? I actually never did that before

Comment: Depends how you're running Django. It's usually either in the console window, server logs or some custom logs.

Comment: `Not Found: /officer/profile
[16/Nov/2017 18:07:43] "GET /officer/profile HTTP/1.1" 404 11212`

These are the 2 lines I am getting from console

Comment: And also setting Debug = False giving me server error 500 as I mentioned earlier

Comment: That's 404 error, not 500 as you said earlier. Move variable handler404 to main `urls.py` file.

Comment: this happened when I am setting Debug = True
and yes in the main urls.py

Comment: I changed it too, but no luck

Comment: @sphoenix, this code is simple. If you are getting `500`, then the only issue can be path to function defined in `handler404` or missing imports. If you have all the required imports, then the only thing that remains is `handler404` variable. Make sure it's right and definitely learn how loggings works. You can't debug without that. Eventually you will have to switch Debug to False.

Comment: Okay, third option is that Django can't locate 404.html template.